# Reload Nginx from Rails without interrupting the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

I have a Rails 4 application that allows users to create applications, everything works fine, but i'm having a problem finalizing the app deployer.

The deployer does some logic and then creates the Nginx host file for the new app and adds it to Nginx `sites-available` and then symlinks it to `sites-enabled`. All this is fine, the problem is that for Nginx to be aware of this new host, it needs to reload, which I am able to do automatically during the deployment but it interrupts the request.

This is the flow:

1 - User clicks on "Deploy" button

2 - Rails controller action does the logic and then makes some system calls including reloading Nginx.

3 - Browser returns a `502 Bad Gateway` **<- PROBLEM**

Then if i reload the page everything is fine and the new app is accessible.

How can I prevent this? I have tried to both use `service nginx reload` and `kill -HUP $( cat /run/nginx.pid )` and get the same result.

Interestingly enough, if i do the deployment of an app already deployed (host file already present in the `sites-available` / `sites-enabled`) the 502 bad gateway doesn't happen.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Adding a 3 seconds `sleep` after the Nginx reload seems to solve the issue, this will do for now but this is hardly the best solution so better ideas are welcome!